# JASPER iReport - Display 2 images in a row in a detail view

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a `SubReport` that gets a list of files paths via `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`. This `SubReport` has a `Title` and a `Detail` band. At this stage the `Detail` band has only one `Image`.

Everything works fine but each `Image` is displayed in one row of the `Detail` band.

[image]

Is it possible to display two images next to each other per row for a n-amount of images? That means if there are 3 images for example, the `Detail` band would have 2 rows; the first containing 2 images and the second containing one image.

[image]

Thanks for your support,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a report that has two horizontally-filled columns.

The report would specify

```
<jasperReport columnCount="2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth=".." columnWidth=".." columnSpacing=".." ...>
```

The detail band would contain a single image element (sized within the column width limit).

Comment: That works beautifully. I added a `SubReport` with 2 columns, placed an `Image` on the first column and set the printOrder to Horizontal. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a `printWhenExpression`. Put all images in the detail and print different set of images on odd and even detail row:

```
<detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="12" y="14" width="172" height="96" uuid="7afa8aa8-0360-466e-94a8-78be647a2de0">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT} & 1) == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:/image1.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="198" y="14" width="172" height="96" uuid="8b3620f2-6001-4bcb-87d8-d479747a99fe">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT} & 1) == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:/image2.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
                        <image>
                <reportElement x="12" y="14" width="172" height="96" uuid="e5776506-fbab-4c13-8a48-cd3de6c33b3a">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT} & 1) == 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:/image3.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I forgot to mention n-amount of images. I have updated the question. In the same time I had an idea. How about returning a list of a list, while the first list contains the amount of images in the row and the second list the amount of rows.

Comment: By the way @PeterMmm I tried your solution with 2 static images in a detail view. After execution the first picture will appear on the left side `$V{REPORT_COUNT} & 1) == 1` in the first row and the second picture will appear on the right `$V{REPORT_COUNT} & 1) == 0`  side in the second row.

Comment: My example is for 3 images. Anyway, where it appears horizontally, depends on the `x` coordinate of the `reportElement`.